# iOS webView displays the content properly but does not allow touching elements

Tags: ios, wkwebview

In my app I have a screen that displays two ViewControllers.
One of them shows a **wkwebview**. This webview shows a graph that I should be able to enlarge and expand by touching.

Sometimes the webview displays the content of the website properly but does not allow to expand / enlarge.
It does allow scrolling up and down so I tend to deny that the ui thread is busy (more than that, the second controller is working properly).
In fact, the element of the graph does not have the ability to click (although through the digger I see that it is).

In fact, the elements on the webview does not have the ability to "touch" on them (although through the safari debugger I see that they are).

This bug sometime happens and sometimes it doesn't. It divides about 50 percent of the time.

What can cause it and how can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: check the frame of view controller that holds the webview and make sure that it is as expected.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr what do you mean "as expected"?